# In Windows 10, how do you install old versions of Ubuntu, such as Ubuntu 8.04 (Hardy Heron) in WSL?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

WSL can install a root tarball (tar.gz), however old versions of Ubuntu, such as Hardy (8.04.3), do not have the -root.tar.gz file available: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/8.04.3/HEADER.html

For C++ development, i.e. compilation of legacy code without errors, is it possible to install Ubuntu 8.04 (Hardy Heron) in WSL? Ideally, there is some approach without creating the -root.tar.gz file manually from VirtualBox. VirtualBox doesn't work because of Hyper-V for Docker (typical issue in dev environment).

I've tried to install https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/hardy/release/unpacked/ using LxRunOffline, but the image doesn't run because the tarball contains a qemu .img for Amazon EC2 and OpenStack cloud. WSL requires a -root.tar.gz which contains the / filesystem.

C:\Users\Jack\Downloads>LxRunOffline run -n hardy
Error: 0x80070040
Press any key to continue...

[image]

Comment: Do you have any Linux distribution installed now in WSL?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I tried to run it but WSL can't.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Correct. The directory structure for WSL must be: https://i.imgur.com/3dbJ2Em.png (taken from Ubuntu 16.04). In the tar.gz of Ubuntu 8.04 (above) we only have a Qemu image hardy-server-cloudimg-amd64.img instead of the extracted rootfs. I've tried to run the img, but Qemu can't run this image. There must be something in the image file that makes it for AWS. So, we need to install Ubuntu 8.04 in a virtual machine and create -root.tar.gz using some command.

Comment: No no, I converted it to the WSL format with 7zip and tar. But it doesn't work. I don't know but does Ubuntu 8.04 binaries has any issue with newer Linux kernel standards?

Comment: @Biswapriyo AFAIK that cloud image of 8.04 can't be used in WSL. It doesn't boot because it's an AWS image. To run Ubuntu 8.04 in WSL, you'd have to create a tarball from Ubuntu 8.04 desktop CD or server installer: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/8.04.3/HEADER.html Have you tried that?